# Why Netbeans suggests making variable final

Tags: java, netbeans, constants

So i have downloaded new `Netbeans 8` version some time ago. In this new version everytime when i declare `private` variable and assign to it value only once  `netbeans` suggests me to make field final because is never changed.

Ok I understand what `final` variable is but ****whats the advantage in declaring `private final int x=3;` variable aka constant over `private int x=3;` and never change it ****

i thought about

1. Concurrency ? - But this doesnt make sense for me if value of non-final variable remains the same whole time
2. Speed ?- I think this may be the reason(some caching ?) but im not sure

Any clarification will be appreciated

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp1029/index.html

Comment: Thanks sir this link provided me lot of usefull answers

Answer (score 3):

Netbeans detects that the variable is actually probably a constant, and suggest for you to declare it as such. This has the advantage of preventing future bugs where this variable is accidentally modified.

Also the final also documents the intention of making this variable a constant, together with the usual notation of defining the constant with all uppercase, which helps understand it's purpose in the program to other developers maintaining the code in the future.